# How can we calculate receptive field of a network includes transposed convolutional layer?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

A network I designed includes transposed convolutional layer.
(ConvTranspose2d in pytorch)

I want to get receptive field size of my network.

Does the concept of receptive field also hold on with transposed convolutional layer?

If yes, then how can I get it?

Comment: [This link](https://medium.com/syncedreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-42f33d4378e0) might be helpful. And [this also](https://fomoro.com/research/article/receptive-field-calculator)

Comment: Second link only support conv2d, but I think I can study with first link. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the library [pytorch-receptive-field](https://github.com/Fangyh09/pytorch-receptive-field) to automatically compute all layers' receptive fields.

Comment: I already tried it, but it did not work with ConvTranspose2d sadly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [torch-scan](https://github.com/frgfm/torch-scan) to automatically compute receptive fields for a lot of layers. It provides support for those layers which are not supported by [pytorch-receptive-field](https://github.com/Fangyh09/pytorch-receptive-field) as well, such as Conv1D, ConvTranspose1D, etc. It also optionally gives effective stride and effective padding as well.

Comment: I already solved it manually... thanks anyway. It could be helpful for other people.